# Is there a way to group names of apps by type main type (e.g. Google Chrome = Google Chrome Ver 11)

Tags: sql

I need to get application names but I need them grouped diregarding the version (e.g. Google Chrome instead of Google Chrome Ver 10, Google Chrome Ver 11 .. etc)

I havent tried anything

No code

Comment: Look up the type of the application in a reference table.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that

Comment: What OS are you using and where are you getting the list of apps from? If they are in a database, what RDMS are you using? What does your list look like? You haven't provided sufficient information.

Comment: The names of apps are in a database table that collects 2M records a week or more. An Example of AppName is Google Chrome 10. I would like to just get all Google grouped into one name. I think my only option is a lookup table. The bad side is there are 37,000 unique apps in this table.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a new field replacing the following with blanks:

1. "Ver"
2. All the numbers
3. Special characters if any